# Scrapy - Sending a new Request/using callback

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Delving deeper than the use of basic scraping functions.

I understand the basic BaseSpider class: name, allowed_domains, and how Request objects are sent for each start_url where the parse function is used as the callback function, and parse receives the Response.

I know my parse function saves an XPath response for data of each class called "service-name", I believe it then proceeds by looping through that data storing each XPath response match into the object "item" which is then sent to the "TgmItem class in my items.py container.

'newUrl' contains the concatenated URL that needs be scraped next, I need to figure out how to get the LinkParse function to scrape each newUrl found, or receive all links for it to scrape individually.

I know meta is used to parse my object item data, and callback gives the Request a function to send the response to.

LinkParse will be used to scrape more data from within all links scraped e.g: "item['test']=link.xpath('test()').extract())"

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "service-name")]')
    for link in links:
        item = TgmItem()
        item['name'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
        item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
        item['newUrl'] = response.url.join(item['link'])
        yield Request(newUrl, meta={'item':item}, callback=self.LinkParse)

def LinkParse(self, response):
    links = response.selector.xpath('*')
    for link in links:
        item = response.request.meta['item']
        item['test'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I know in the callback function you parse a response (web page) which I need to be all or each link (but I think to solve this, I have to send the current response.url and deal with each/all link(s) in the ParseLink function.

I'm getting an error saying newUrl is not defined, guessing the Request can't accept that.

I'm not expecting any help here, if someone could please point me in the right direction, or something to research further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newUrl` variable is not defined. Instead use `item['newUrl']`:

```
yield Request(item['newUrl'], meta={'item': item}, callback=self.LinkParse)
```

Also, `response.url.join()` call doesn't make sense to me. If you want combine the `response.url` with an `href` attribute value, use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
item['newUrl'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
```

Besides, I'm not sure what are you trying to do in the `LinkParse` callback. As far as I understand you want to follow "service-name" links and get additional data for each link. Then, I don't see why you need that `for link in links` loop in the `LinkParse()` method.

As far as I understand, your `LinkParse()` method should look like this:

```
def LinkParse(self, response):
    newfield = response.selector.xpath('//myfield/text()').extract()
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['newfield'] = newfield  
    return item
```

Comment: Appreciate your help again, thanks! This is starting to make sense now. I'm curious, from given code would LinkParse contain all the data available to the parse function because of the callback and meta?

Comment: @RespectForDaHerb in `LinkParse` `response.meta['item']` would contain the `item` instance with all the fields you've filled up in `parse()`. It is like you are filling the same data but in 2 places: in one method you fill what is available on one page, in the other what is available on the other page. Sorry, my english is not that good to explain it clearly. But I hope it makes sense.